# fetching startdate and enddate from timestemp column and partition by modes in SQL

Tags: sql

i am trying to solve this this is `table1` and i am trying to have below `output` i am not able to build up a logic that how could i fetch start date and end date from same `timestemp` column in SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `batch` INTEGER,
  `timestemp` VARCHAR(8),
  `mo` INTEGER,
  `speed` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`batch`, `timestemp`, `mo`, `speed`)
VALUES
  ('1', '00:18:00', '0', '0'),
  ('1', '01:18:00', '0', '0'),
  ('1', '02:18:00', '0', '0'),
  ('1', '03:18:00', '1', '5'),
  ('1', '04:18:00', '1', '6'),
  ('1', '05:18:00', '1', '7'),
  ('1', '06:18:00', '2', '10'),
  ('1', '07:18:00', '2', '9'),
  ('1', '08:18:00', '2', '8'),
  ('1', '09:18:00', '3', '12'),
  ('1', '10:18:00', '3', '23'),
  ('1', '11:18:00', '3', '21'),
  ('1', '12:18:00', '4', '20'),
  ('1', '13:18:00', '4', '22');
```

mo=mode

| batch | timestemp | mo | speed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:18:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 01:18:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 02:18:00 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 03:18:00 | 1 | 5 |
| 1 | 04:18:00 | 1 | 6 |
| 1 | 05:18:00 | 1 | 7 |
| 1 | 06:18:00 | 2 | 10 |
| 1 | 07:18:00 | 2 | 9 |
| 1 | 08:18:00 | 2 | 8 |
| 1 | 09:18:00 | 3 | 12 |
| 1 | 10:18:00 | 3 | 23 |
| 1 | 11:18:00 | 3 | 21 |
| 1 | 12:18:00 | 4 | 20 |
| 1 | 13:18:00 | 4 | 22 |

ooutput:

| batch | start time | end time | mode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 00:18:00 | 03:17:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 03:18:00 | 06:17:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 06:18:00 | 09:17:00 | 2 |
| 1 | 09:18:00 | 12:17:00 | 3 |
| 1 | 12:18:00 | 13:18:00 | 4 |

Comment: Provide the output for `SELECT VERSION();`

Comment: Post sample data as CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO scripts, not as a table.

Comment: @Akina version 8.0.29 however you can solve using anything any DB does not have to be specific by only specific DB.

Comment: Each DBMS have its own SQL dialect. There is no universal solution in most cases. In general - there is a solution which uses CTE and window functions, and a solution without them (which is more complex). Anycase - this is "gaps and islands" standard task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (
  `batch` INTEGER,
  `timestemp` TIME,
  `mo` INTEGER,
  `speed` INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO table1
  (`batch`, `timestemp`, `mo`, `speed`)
VALUES
  ('1', '00:18:00', '0', '0'),
  ('1', '01:18:00', '0', '0'),
  ('1', '02:18:00', '0', '0'),
  ('1', '03:18:00', '1', '5'),
  ('1', '04:18:00', '1', '6'),
  ('1', '05:18:00', '1', '7'),
  ('1', '06:18:00', '2', '10'),
  ('1', '07:18:00', '2', '9'),
  ('1', '08:18:00', '2', '8'),
  ('1', '09:18:00', '3', '12'),
  ('1', '10:18:00', '3', '23'),
  ('1', '11:18:00', '3', '21'),
  ('1', '12:18:00', '4', '20'),
  ('1', '13:18:00', '4', '22');
```

---

**Query**

```
SELECT batch
     , mode
     , start_time
     , COALESCE(SUBTIME(LEAD(start_time) OVER (ORDER BY start_time), '00:01:00'), end_time) end_time
FROM (
  SELECT batch
       , min(timestemp) start_time
       , max(timestemp) end_time
       , mo mode
  FROM table1
  GROUP BY batch, mo
  ) min_max;
```

| batch | mode | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 00:18:00 | 03:17:00 |
| 1 | 1 | 03:18:00 | 06:17:00 |
| 1 | 2 | 06:18:00 | 09:17:00 |
| 1 | 3 | 09:18:00 | 12:17:00 |
| 1 | 4 | 12:18:00 | 13:18:00 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/89QkyCirSiYFmN49ot72eJ/3)

Comment: If nothing else, this provides a `CREATE TABLE` for those too lazy to copy/paste the table into `Text to DDL` on `db-fiddle`...

Comment: Double Check the output, as mine doesn't quite match what you've given, there'd still be a bit more to fill in the gaps if that's really what's needed.

Comment: yes @BeRT2me out need to me `-1 minute` from next mode, i wanted to figure out logic for that only. if you could help please